# Selenium/python - fails to find partial link text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium with Python 2.7 on Windows 10 running the Chrome driver (as a script and from the python REPL) fails to find an element by partial link text, and I'm not sure why. When I look at the source code of the webpage in question, there is only one instance of `WO20` in the entire page, and it's in a link, but selenium returns `no such element`.

Here's an example (the `WO20` comes just after the `href`):

```
<a id="resultTable:0:resultListTableColumnLink" name="resultTable:0:resultListTableColumnLink" href="detail.jsf?docId=WO2015102036&amp;recNum=1&amp;office=&amp;queryString=FP%3A%28JP2014005719%29&amp;prevFilter=&amp;sortOption=Pub+Date+Desc&amp;maxRec=3" target="_self"><span class="notranslate"> WO/2015/102036</span></a>
```

The page has a few other links, but the one I need is the only one with the character combination `WO20`, so in theory this should be easy to identify. My guess is that selenium isn't recognizing this as a link, which is why `partial_link_text` isn't working. I've tried using `xpath` (successfully), but the problem is that that returns the n-th link in the table, and the links I need (I'm processing multiple documents) aren't in a fixed position.

Comment: can you share your source code?

Comment: `elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="resultTable:0:resultListTableColumnLink"]''')` ... I think. I just replaced it in the script with the other answerer's suggestion, so it's gone. My original code worked, in that it identified an element, but only by position in a table, and not by the content of the link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, there is no link text that contain `WO20`! I think you confuse link text with `href` attribute of `<a>` element. You can find target element by link text/partial link text with following code:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('WO/2015/102036')
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('WO/20')
```

this `XPaths` should be applicable also:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "WO20")]')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "WO/20")]')
```

Comment: I can't use the first one, because the numbers of the files are always different (although WO/20 is always the same), but the other three work. Thanks!

Comment: this answer is really unclear can you explain in more detail? Why is it that your solution works and his did not?