# How to click a button from Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Anaconda2, Jupiter, and Chrome browser.

I am writing below code which is running successfully but now I want to click on button.

```
<a href="#" action="exportSelected" class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></i> Export
</a>
```

What should I write in Python to access this?

```
find_element_by_partial_link_text('btn btn-default').click()
```

It's giving an error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium/python - fails to find partial link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36951405/selenium-python-fails-to-find-partial-link-text)

Comment: You should probably spend some time reading through the python/selenium docs to learn the different locators, how they work, and how to use them. http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Answer (score 5):

`"btn btn-default"` is not a *link text*, but *class names*.

You can use one of below solutions:

- Locate by exact link text:

  ```
  find_element_by_link_text('Export').click()
  ```
- Locate by compound class name:

  ```
  find_element_by_css_selector('a.btn.btn-default').click()
  ```
- Locate by `action` attribute

  ```
  find_element_by_css_selector('a[action="exportSelected"]').click()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all replying me and suggesting pyhthon doc. appreciate it.

So i have used very simple lines to get my job done.

**driver.find_element_by_xpath('copy your xpath').** 
which is very simple

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app_content"]/div[2]/div/div/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a[1]').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="export_button"]').click()