# Python selenium webdriver select href select partial text

Tags: python, css, selenium, element, partial

I'm using Python 3.8.5 on Ubuntu 20.04. Using selenium webdriver on chrome, I want to download the attachment by specifying the `licenceId` number (1467250) which is included in this element:

```
<a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" href="#" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.forms['myApplicationsResultsForm'],'myApplicationsResultsForm:searchResultsTable:0:j_id339:0:j_id340,myApplicationsResultsForm:searchResultsTable:0:j_id339:0:j_id340,licenceId,1467250,statusHistoryId,2600790,fileName,ROL_1467250_20200817-142839.pdf,attachmentType,ROL','');}return false" class="pageLink"><img src="/oplinc2/images/pdf.jpg" alt="ROL_1467250_20200817-142839.pdf" height="24" style="border-width: 0px;" title="ROL_1467250_20200817-142839.pdf" width="24" /></a>
```

I am able to download this link by clicking on the css_selector:

```
pdf = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#myApplicationsResultsForm\:searchResultsTable\:0\:j_id335 > a')

pdf.click()
```

Am I able to use partial text within the element to locate and download attachment eg. `licenceID, 1467250`? There are many of these attachments. I tried the partial text example [from the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) but this didn't work for me:

```
>>> driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('1467250')

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"1467250"}
```

**Edit**
This question is similar to @Ajay link to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36951405/selenium-python-fails-to-find-partial-link-text) except this element has slightly different href. Still not sure how to access `onclick`

Comment: Can you provide the link to that web page?

Comment: Sorry, no this is a private account with username and password

Comment: `find_elements_by_partial_link_text` method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36951405/selenium-python-fails-to-find-partial-link-text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium/python - fails to find partial link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36951405/selenium-python-fails-to-find-partial-link-text)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I've tried three solutions: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "1467250")]')`
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@onclick, "1467250")]')`
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "1467250")]')`
Any suggestions of how to access the `onclick` section of the element?

Comment: can you provide a link to a page that has a similar behavior but is accessible by others?

Comment: Sorry @glamredhel, I can't find another table with attachments like this. I can't pass on user/password either.

Comment: did you try ```driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(., "1467250")]')``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@onclick, "1467250")]')
```

Replacing the `a` with `*` finds the element.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('https://websites.com/activation.php?a=act')

for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```